# I get "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" in Wordpress under Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, wordpress, ubuntu-12.04

I've added a post in Wordpress and when I try to see it in my browser I get error 500.

This is the configuration in apache.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName new.comelody.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/website/wordpress

  <Directory /var/www/website/wordpress>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is Apache's debug log:

```
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 31.168.149.202] r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 31.168.149.202] redirected from r->uri = /2016/09/19/a-good-article/
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 31.168.149.202] Zlib: Compressed 620 to 380 : URL /test/index.php
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#b96cdc20 [mem: b96d3eab]
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [info] [client 74.82.47.4] (70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed.
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Mon Sep 19 09:11:57 2016] [info] [client 74.82.47.4] Connection closed to child 6 with standard shutdown (server comelody.com:443)
[Mon Sep 19 09:12:06 2016] [error] [client 66.249.75.12] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is most probably your .htaccess.

Comment: "What is wrong here?" - the obvious. You seem to be i na redirect loop where any request (ANY) is redirected to /test/index.php - EVEN if it is a request for this URL, which means the redirewts never stop.

Answer (score 0):

There was a rule in my .htaccess file

```
#RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
```

That caused the problem.